# MIPS architecture loop help required

Tags: mips, mips32, pcspim

Complete the SPIM assembly language program loop2.s.
The program will calculate the sum of the elements in "numbers" 
whose value is less than or equal to 1000.

I tried to program the code, however the output is coming , whereas i need it to be 11

Program Name:   loop2.s

- will calculate the sum of all elements in the array "numbers"
  whose value is less than or equal to 1000.
- "numbers" is an array with 5 integer elements.
- "count" holds the number of elements in "numbers".
- Output format must be 
  "sum = 11"

t0 - points to array elements in turn
t1 - contains a count of elements

t2 - contains sum

t3 - each word from the array "numbers" in turn

```
#################################################
#                                               #
#               text segment                    #
#                                               #
#################################################

        .text
        .globl __start
__start:                # execution starts here


#   Put your answer between dashed lines.
#
#------------------Your code starts next line---------------
  la $t0, numbers
   lw $t1, count
   li $t2, 0

   process:
       lw $t3, ($t0)           # load word from the array
       add $t2, $t2, $t3       # add it to sum
       add $t0, $t0, 4           # increment the pointer / get the next element of the array
       sub $t1, $t1, 1           # decrement the counter
       beqz $t1, done           # if counter = 0, then it's done
       j process

   done:
       la $a0, ans1
       li $v0, 4  
       syscall

       move $a0, $t2
       li $v0, 1
       syscall

       la $a0, endl
       li $v0, 4
       syscall

       li $v0, 10
       syscall
#-----------------Your code ends above this line----------------

    la $a0,endl # syscall to print out
    li $v0,4    # a new line
    syscall 

    li $v0,10   # Exit
    syscall     # Bye!


#################################################
#                                               #
#               data segment                    #
#                                               #
#################################################

        .data
    numbers:    
        .word 3,2000,2,6,3000
    count:  .word 5

    ans1:   .asciiz "sum = "
    endl:   .asciiz "\n"       

##
##  end of file loop2.s
```

Comment: _"however the output is coming , whereas i need it to be 11"_ Please clarify what _"the output is coming"_ means. Obviously you need some sort of comparison and conditional branch if you want to exclude certain elements.I suggest that you go through a MIPS instruction set reference to see which instructions are available that you could make use of.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add code that checks whether the value is <= 1000 (or > 1000) to either do (or don't) add the number to $t2.

```
process:
   lw $t3, ($t0)           # load word from the array

   # check if > 1000, and if it is, jump to don't_add (ie: skip the adding to sum)
   bgt $t3, 1000, dont_add


   add $t2, $t2, $t3       # add it to sum
dont_add:    
   add $t0, $t0, 4         # increment the pointer / get the next element of the array
   sub $t1, $t1, 1         # decrement the counter
   beqz $t1, done          # if counter = 0, then it's done
   j process

done:
```

Comment: You should also replace the `beqz/j` instructions at the end by the unique instruction `bne $t1, $zero, process`